# Apps Script: How to apply RichTextValue() only to certain column?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Apps Script, I want to write my API JSON data into a Google Sheet. My original request was to simply write the data into Google Sheet for which the following function works well.

```
function original_func() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var data = [
    {"track":{"name":"Song1","album":"Album1","id":"ABC","url":"www.example.com/1"}},
    {"track":{"name":"Song2","album":"Album2","id":"XYZ","url":"www.example.com/2"}}
  ];
  var headers = [["id","name","album","url"]];
  var keys = ["track.id","track.name","track.album","track.url"];

  // Set headers
  sheet.getRange(1,1,1,headers[0].length).setValues(headers);

  // Write to sheet
  for (let i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let arr = Array(keys.map(k => k.split('.').reduce((a, b) => a[b], data[i])));
    sheet.getRange(i+2,1,1,headers[0].length).setValues(arr);
  }

}
```

My requirements have now changed, wherein I want to use the url provided in the data and use the RichTextValue Class to add it to the id itself. I was able to achieve it using the following function,

```
function modified_func() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    
  var data = [
    {"track":{"name":"Song1","album":"Album1","id":"ABC","url":"www.example.com/1"}},
    {"track":{"name":"Song2","album":"Album2","id":"XYZ","url":"www.example.com/2"}}
  ];

  // Headers
  var columnNames = ["id", "name","album"];
  var columnCount = columnNames.length;

  // Set Headers
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, columnCount).setValues([columnNames]);

  // Write the data to the sheet
  var rowData = data.map(function(obj) {
    return columnNames.map(function(key) {
      var value = obj.track[key];
      if (key === "id") {
        var richTextValue = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
          .setText(value)
          .setLinkUrl(obj.track.url)
          .build();
        return richTextValue;
      }
      return value;
    });
  });
  var rowCount = rowData.length;

  // Loop through each cell and set value accordingly
  for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
      var cell = sheet.getRange(i + 2, j + 1);
      if (columnNames[j] === "id") {
        cell.setRichTextValue(rowData[i][j]);
      } else {
        cell.setValue(rowData[i][j]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, compared to the original method, the modified method does achieve my intended result, but the code doesn't look concise and is not optimized.

How do I optimize my `modified_func` to achieve the same functionality? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function modified_func() {
  var data = [
    { "track": { "name": "Song1", "album": "Album1", "id": "ABC", "url": "www.example.com/1" } },
    { "track": { "name": "Song2", "album": "Album2", "id": "XYZ", "url": "www.example.com/2" } },
    { "track": { "name": 1, "album": 2, "id": 3, "url": "www.example.com/2" } }
  ];
  var columnNames = ["id", "name", "album"];

  // Create rich text values.
  var richTextValues = [
    columnNames.map(c => SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(c).build()),
    ...data.map(({ track }) =>
      columnNames.map(c => {
        var rt = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(track[c]);
        if (c == "id") rt.setLinkUrl(track.url);
        return rt.build();
      })
    )
  ];

  // Put rich text values into cells.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, richTextValues.length, richTextValues[0].length).setRichTextValues(richTextValues);
}
```

- When this script is run, the same result with your `modified_func` is obtained. And, in this case, the process cost might be able to be reduced a little from your `modified_func`.

#### Reference:

- [setRichTextValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setrichtextvaluesvalues)

Comment: You are absolutely amazing, Tanaike! This is what I was exactly looking for. 

Although, I just noticed that the actual data has nested keys. So, can you guide me on how to get to the nested level as well? Here is the keys for the dataset.

`var keys = ["track.id", "track.name", "track.artists.0.name", "track.album.name", "track.external_urls.spotify", "added_at"];`

Comment: @Shantanu Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question `Although, I just noticed that the actual data has nested keys. So, can you guide me on how to get to the nested level as well?`, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand it. Can I ask you about the relationship between your new question and `var keys = ["track.id", "track.name", "track.artists.0.name", "track.album.name", "track.external_urls.spotify", "added_at"];`? First, I would like to correctly understand your new question.

Comment: My apologies on the confusion. The `keys` are the object keys of the actual data. In my `original_func()`, you can see the sample of the `keys` and the way it is mapped. Following is the actual data for the above `keys` that I need to map.
`[{track={id=ABC, name=Song1, album={name=Album1}, artists{[name=Artist1]}}, added_at=today}];`

Comment: @Shantanu Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. I cannot still understand your new question. What is `[{track={id=ABC, name=Song1, album={name=Album1}, artists{[name=Artist1]}}, added_at=today}];`? I think that it is not a JSON object. I'm very confusing your new question. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. But, I would like to support you. So, can I ask you about the detail of your new question? I believe that when I could correctly understand your new question, I can resolve it.

Comment: @Shantanu I cannot still understand the relationship between `var keys = ["track.id", "track.name", "track.artists.0.name", "track.album.name", "track.external_urls.spotify", "added_at"];` and `[{track={id=ABC, name=Song1, album={name=Album1}, artists{[name=Artist1]}}, added_at=today}];` and your new question. Can I ask you about the detail of it? I could understand your 1st question and resolve it. But, I cannot still understand your new question. I really apologize for my very poor English skill. But, I would like to support you. So, can I ask you about the detail of your new question?

Comment: @Shantanu I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again.  Although I could understand your 1st question, resolve it and I have been also continuing to try to understand your new question, unfortunately, I cannot still understand your new question. I'm worried that I might trouble you because I cannot resolve your new question soon. So, in this case, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question. By this, it will help a lot of users think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'd be glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Thanks, Tanaike for your help and patience. I will post a new question soon.

Comment: Hey Tanaike, please check my profile for my new question. Thanks for helping.